# Would f(n) = O(g(n) + h(n)) imply the relationship between f(n), g(n), and h(n)?

Tags: asymptotics

I come across the following claim:

For all positive, increasing function $f$, $g$, and $h$, if we have $f(n) \in O(g(n) + h(n))$, then we can conclude that either $g(n)\in \Omega(f(n))$ or $h(n) \in \Omega(f(n))$, or both of them are correct. (We say that a function $f$ is positive and increasing, if we can get that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$ and $f(x) > f(y)$ if we have $x > y \geq 0$.)

To me, it seems like it is a correct claim. Here are my thoughts.

From $f(n)\in O(g(n) + h(n))$, we get to know that $f(n)\leq c(g(n) + h(n))$. For $g(n)\in \Omega(f(n))$ and $h(n)\in \Omega(f(n))$, we get to know that $g(n)\geq c_2f(n)$ or $h(n)\geq c_3f(n)$. I just feel like in order to get $f(n)\leq c(g(n) + h(n))$, then at least one of $g(n)\geq c_2f(n)$ and $h(n)\geq c_3f(n)$ should hold. If not, then we can only get something like $g(n) + h(n)\leq f(n)$.

And I also can't think of a counter example about it.

I am not sure it is true or not? If it is false, could you please give out a counter example?

Comment: What have you tried so far to prove or disprove its correctness? Thinking of counter examples is a good start but you should try formally proving one way or the other if you can't think of counter examples.

Comment: At least one of g(n) ≥ c2 f(n) and h(n) ≥ c3 f(n) holds for each individual n. But you would need that one of them holds for _each_ large n. Can you construct an example where g(n) ≥ c2 f(n) for even, but not for odd n, and h(n) ≥ c3 f(n) holds for odd, but not for even n?

Comment: I am sorry I don't quite understand. Why we need to consider even and odd here?

Comment: I think gnasher proposes to construct a counterexample where $f(n)<=c \cdot g(n)$ for odd $n$ and $f(n) \le c \cdot h(n)$ for even $n$ but $g(n)<=d \cdot f(n)$ for even $n$ and $h(n) \le d \cdot f(n)$ for odd $n$.

Comment: @fear: Exactly what miracle173 said. I'm 99.9% convinced that there is a counter example, and my suggestion will lead to the simplest counter example.